# Round SQL 2 digits

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset, rounding, query-builder

There are plenty of possibilities online but none of them works to me. 
I'm using 'ROUND' in my query to round up decimals to 2 digits but when a value is like 2.5, the functions shows 2.5 instead of 2.50

Any idea to fix this? Please rewrite my query with your solution and I'll try it immediately.

ps: I'm using this query in vb.net to fill a dataset.

```
SELECT         
    p.ProductNaam, f.Aantal, p.Prijs, f.BasisBedrag, f.Korting, 
    ROUND(f.BasisBedrag * (f.Korting / 100.00), 2) AS Expr1005, 
    ROUND(f.BasisBedrag - f.BasisBedrag * (f.Korting / 100), 2) AS Expr1006, 
    p.Btw, 
    ROUND((f.BasisBedrag - f.BasisBedrag * (f.Korting / 100.0)) * (p.Btw / 100.0), 2) AS Expr1008, 
    f.TotaalBedrag, p.ProductID
FROM
    (tblFactuur f 
INNER JOIN
    tblProducten p ON f.ProductID = p.ProductID)
WHERE
    (f.FactuurID = '2014001')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using Access, I think the Format function might be the one you are looking for. The "Standard" option will give you 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT        p.ProductNaam, 
              f.Aantal, p.Prijs, f.BasisBedrag, f.Korting, 
              Format(ROUND(f.BasisBedrag * (f.Korting / 100.00), 2), "Standard") AS Expr1005, 
              Format(ROUND(f.BasisBedrag - f.BasisBedrag * (f.Korting / 100), 2), "Standard") AS Expr1006, 
              p.Btw, 
              Format(ROUND((f.BasisBedrag - f.BasisBedrag * (f.Korting / 100.0)) * (p.Btw / 100.0), 2), "Standard") AS Expr1008, 
              f.TotaalBedrag, p.ProductID
FROM            (tblFactuur f INNER JOIN
                     tblProducten p ON f.ProductID = p.ProductID)
WHERE        (f.FactuurID = '2014001')
```

Comment: Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression

Comment: oh, I assumed you were using Sql Server

Comment: Read my ps :) I'm using vb.net

Comment: I meant for your RDBMS.

Comment: Ow sorry, No the data is coming from an Access database.

Comment: @Timvdb1992 I think the Format function may give you what you are looking for. My experience of Access is limited however.

Comment: Perfect!! Kind regards!